# Why is there a Remote Desktop Connnection link in Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-10-apps

In Windows 10 Home, why is there a 'Remote Desktop Connnection' link in: Start Menu > Windows Accessories, when I've read that Windows 10 Home doesn't support Remote Desktop Connection?

It is on a newly installed system, not an addition.

What purpose does the included settings box serve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The included settings box is for connecting to *other* systems.

Windows "Home" edition doesn't support acting as a Remote Desktop server, i.e. it cannot accept *inbound* RDP connections – but that has nothing to do with it making outbound connections to other machines.

(As is often the case, the components involved in a client and in a server are separate. Accepting logins via RDP requires deep integration with the system, while the client is a completely normal app that only needs to use network and draw stuff on screen.)

Comment: [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-allow-access) is the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the informative reply. So, to confirm, for Remote Desktop to work, both PCs do not need to be Windows 10 Pro or above, and the PC viewing another can be a Windows 10 Home PC? And without having to use a 'wrapper', as described here for example: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-use-windows-10-remote-desktop-in-windows-home-rdp

Comment: The "wrapper's" website talks about patching termsrv.dll – that's the "RDP server" side.